# How to create an app to push jobs to delivery drivers

Tags: android

I have a web application where a user can define parcel collection jobs and assign them to a driver.  I want the user to be able to push the details of a job to a driver's Android phone.  Do I need to write a specific app for the driver or can I make use of standard Android components e.g. calendar, maps, camera?

Requirements:

- the driver gets notified of a new job
- by opening the job the driver sees a map of the collection points (there may be more than one per job) and the optimal route between them

Desirable:

- the driver can change the status of a job to accepted or complete
- the driver can take a photo of the parcel and upload it so it becomes viewable in the web application
- the web application user can cancel or amend a job

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You'll need an app to get notifications and map points. This question really is off-topic for SO, as you're not asking a specific programming question, but rather seeking design advice.

Answer (score 0):

The scope is really bulky and u put inside notification ....

what you can do is use google gcm service and its for free in the message itself you can send data from server in json format and parse dat in the user side then you can show him a screen after parsing to do any action like accept or decline... etc.. etc...

thx